# Select record based on max(date) accross multiple tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, max

I have two tables: 1 for an initial assessment and 1 for reassessments.  The format is as such:

`initialAssessment`:

- `assessmentId`
- `personId`
- `assessmentDate`
- `totalScore`

`Reassessments`:

- `assessmentId`
- `personId`
- `assessmentDate`
- `totalScore`

Each table contains 1 record per person.  It is possible that the most recent assessment is not contained in the reassessment table.  For that reason I need to select the most recent assessment between the two tables and the corresponding total score for a given person.  I have tried the following query but I get multiple rows:

```
 SELECT personId, MAX(assessmentDate) AS maxSubmittedDt, TotalScore
 FROM (
    SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
    FROM  initialAssessment
    WHERE personId = 1
    UNION
    SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
    FROM Reassessments
    WHERE personId = 1) AS u
 Group BY personId, TotalScore
 Order By personId
```

My question is, how can I select the most recent assessment and its corresponding score between the intial assessment and the reassessment tables?  If it matters, I'm using SQl server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
FROM (
     SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by personId Order by assessmentDate desc) as RowId
     FROM (
        SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
        FROM  initialAssessment
        WHERE personId = 1
        UNION
        SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
        FROM Reassessments
        WHERE personId = 1
      ) a
) b
WHERE RowId = 1
```

It will be something like this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308281/How-to-Use-ROW_NUMBER-to-Enumerate-and-Partition-R

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your SQL does not apply the alias "u" that you created from the nested union.  Also, your main select is not applying the personId that is being applied in the Group By below. Try the following:

```
SELECT u.personId AS offenderCD, MAX(u.assessmentDate) AS maxSubmittedDt, u.TotalScore
FROM (
SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
FROM  initialAssessment
WHERE personId = 1

UNION

SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
FROM Reassessments
WHERE personId = 1) AS u
Group BY u.personId, u.assessmentDate, u.TotalScore
Order By u.personId
```

Comment: you can't do group by and then have some columns in the select list that don't have aggregate functions applied to them

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to query for a single person only, you could just use TOP (n) + ORDER BY:

```
SELECT TOP (1) personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
FROM (
    SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
    FROM  initialAssessment
    WHERE personId = 1
    UNION
    SELECT personId, assessmentDate, TotalScore
    FROM Reassessments
    WHERE personId = 1) AS u
) s
ORDER BY assessmentDate DESC
;
```

[@Brian White's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897563/297408), however, is applicable regardless of how many people's results you want to get in one query.